# =PSET 2 CAESAR= How do I convert ASCII range down to a value from 0 to 25?

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I first did this:

```
// Convert ASCII range down to a value from 0 to 25

char uppercase[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char lowercase[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char convertedUppercase[27];
char convertedLowercase[27];

for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
{
    convertedUppercase[i] = uppercase[i] - 'A';
    convertedLowercase[i] = lowercase[i] - 'a';
}

// For each character in the plaintext: (DOESN'T WORK)

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i <= n; i++)
{
    // Rotate the character if it's a letter // ci = (pi + k) % 26

    if (isalpha(p[i]))
    {
        if (isupper(p[i]))
        {
            c[i] = ((p[i]) + k) % 26;
        }
        else if (islower(p[i]))
        {
            c[i] = ((p[i]) + k) % 26;
        }
    }
}

printf("ciphertext: %s\n", c);
```

but then I realized that the value of `convertedUppercase` will just be like 0 = NUL instead of 0 = A. Can anyone give me a hint what to do?

edit:

From the CS50 Discord:

"The caesar cipher formula (p + k) % 26 works on the premise that p (the plain text character) has a value of 0 - 25  (representing a - z or A - Z)

So if your plain char is 'x', that would have a value of 23, and if your key was 2, then the ciphered char would be:

```
(23 + 2) % 26
(  25  ) % 26
= 25  'z'
```

I'm kinda lost on how to do it.

Comment: Pleae explain the purpose of you code in more detail (directly here, i.e. not by "see PSET"),  provide a [mre] of your attempt, along with sample input, current output, desired output. Ideally demonstrat without requiring user input.

Comment: "be like 0 = NUL" I suspect that is actually the goal. You want an array which has the numbers 0-25 in the same indices where `uppercase` has A-Z, don't you? In that case yes, the entry on index 0 will be 0 which is the same as the `NUL` character. Also, you will have the value 2 at index 2 and the value 24 at index 24. Spot a pattern?

Comment: By the way I think you want `i < 26` instead of `i <= 26`. Just a guess, becaue with A at index 0 you will find Z at index 25 and I do not know what you want to do with what you find behind Z. I guess you do not want to do anything with it and instead write 0 in the destination array at that index, outside of the loop.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry for not making it clear, I edit the post to include an example.

Comment: You only have alphabets in your code. I think you really should embrace the notion of having input. If you do similar things to input (instead to an alphabet) you might find out that the 0 is not confusing at all. Especialyl if not followed by 1,2,3,4,....25. So please, provide a [mre] and sample input, along with desired output. I think it will give you an insight.

Comment: Subtracting `'A'` from an upper-case letter will give a number in the range 0..25; subtracinting `'a'` from a lower-case letter will give a number in the range 0..25 too.  Adding those character codes back will convert 0..25 into a letter again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be so much easier if you would provide a MRE.
I guess what you are observing is that you see a truncated cipertext if you attempt to output it via `printf()` with `"%s"`.
This is however only because any "A" (that is a ciper A, i.e. after shifting by key) results in a 0 (which terminates string output, being the `'\0'` terminator) and most other letters result in unprintable characters.

This is because you only shift by key and map to 0-25 what needs to be the number representation (i.e. numeric instead of textual ciper) here:

```
c[i] = ((p[i]) + k) % 26;
```

In order to turn into textual cipher instead of numeric ciper, you need to do

- convert textual to numeric, with  `-'A'`
- shift by key, with `+k`
- map to 0-25, with `%26`
- convert numeric to textual, with `+'A'`

I.e.

```
c[i] = ((p[i]-'A') + k) % 26 + 'A';
```

E.g. "H" from "Hello World".

- textual to numeric, 'H' - 'A' -> 7
- shift by key, 7 + 4 -> 11
- map to 0-25, 11%26 -> 11
- numeric to textual, 11 + 'A' -> 'L' is cipher

E.g. "W" from "Hello World".

- textual to numeric, 'W' - 'A' -> 22
- shift by key, 22 + 4 -> 26
- map to 0-25, 26%26 -> 0
- numeric to textual, 0 + 'A' -> 'A' is cipher